# Adding "Upload Image" to Sign up Form in a WordPress based website

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Unfortunately adding "Upload Image" to sign up form of a WordPress website is not possible. During initial registration, WordPress can not save the avatar, because there is no user id. Only after the user confirm the email address, WordPress can create a user id for the user.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this issue, I really need this option for a dating website.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/prompt-users-to-upload-avatar-on-registration

Answer (score 0):

use any plugin to create custom sign up or login page in your site like

1. https://wpforms.com/
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/

Comment: Thanks. The first one is not free. Is the second one 100% free?